# MongoDB selecting all where an array is non-empty, 2 different results

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I found two different syntaxes for querying in mongo where an array is non-empty.  I imagine the crux of this may actually be my data rather than the query, but in the event mongo is doing some null-shenanigans I don't understand, I wanted to check here---what is the preferred way of selecting documents where the 'institution.tags' array is ["populated", "and"] not []?

First option---check that the 0-th item of the array exists:

```
> db.coll.find({'institution.tags.0': {'$exists':true}}).count()
7330
```

Second option---check that this list field is not null:

```
> db.coll.find({'institution.tags': {"$ne":null}}).count()
28014
```

In theory, all fields named 'institution.tags' are an array type---I don't expect any to be dictionary-types, strings, or numbers.  But I do otherwise see dramatically different counts, so I'm wondering what I should be expecting, and which query is better both semantically (is it doing what I think it is doing) or for performance.

Comment: Your second query will include docs where `institution.tags == []` while the first one excludes them.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet from the Mongo shell should clarify your question:

```
> db.coll.insert({_id:1})
> db.coll.insert({_id:2, array: []})
> db.coll.insert({_id:3, array: ["entry"]})
> db.coll.insert({_id:4, array: "no_array"})
> db.coll.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "array" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "array" : [ "entry" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "array" : "no_array" }
> db.coll.count({array: {$exists:true}})
3
> db.coll.count({array: {$ne:null}})
3
> db.coll.count({"array.0": {$exists:true}})
1
> db.coll.count({$and: [{$where: "Array.isArray(this.array)"}, {array: {$size: {$gt: 0}}}]})
1
```

Your first option is probably the right way to go, but if you want to be as explicit as possible have a look at the last query in my example which uses [$where to check the $type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) as well as [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/). Your second option simply checks if the field exists, you will not know

- whether it is an array
- or - if so - whether it is empty